# Updated: How to interact "directly" with smart contract via a micro-controller?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, oracles, external-api, iot

Assume we have a `micro-controller` and it collects a meta-data (ex. a payload as a string). How this `micro-controller` can interact **"directly"** with smart contract to write this data to the blockchain?

Must we use something like [Oraclize](https://docs.oraclize.it/#home)? Since [a smart contract cannot interact **directly** with an external source.](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-a-dapp-using-truffle-oraclize-ethereum-bridge-and-webpack-9cb84b8f6bcb)

And also, do we need to install, **"necessarily"**, a **Geth** or **Parity** client on this `micro-controller`?

Is there a practical / existing example for such a scenario?

**From my point of view,** this `micro-controller` can collect data and then by calling a function in smart contract (ex. `writePayload()`) writes data in the blockchain **"without"** using an oracle such as **Oraclize**.

**Note:** According to the comments on this question: [Is it possible to call a function of smart contract "without" installing "Geth" or "Parity"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/57836/23024) , isn't it **easier** to use `infura` as an **existing node**, instead of installing `Geth` or `Parity` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can't access smart contracts "directly". Something like Oraclize wouldn't help you much with that either.

You will always need an intermediary node which is connected to the Ethereum blockchain and it will provide you with access to the blockchain.

You don't "necessarily" need Geth or Parity, they are used for creating and maintaining the node. At least you don't need them on the controllers. As your micro-controllers are probably lacking in capabilities, I suggest you use a centralized node (or multiple) with which all your controllers communicate.

Comment: Thank you, However, in this example ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BrvGnuGteI)), the device is based on an `ESP8266` which connects to a router running an instance of a `Geth` Ethereum node. It uses the Ethereum blockchain to control an LED connected to the `ESP8266` using a smart contract. Meaning that apparently, it could be possible to use a `micro-controller` as an *Ethereum node* by installing *Geth* or *Parity* on `micro-controller`, then we have a node that is capable to interact directly with Ethereum blockchain. What do you think?

Comment: Or this example ([Elkrem](https://devpost.com/software/elkrem-development-board-for-iot-ethereum)) where they use a *Nano Pi* as a linux board to run the Ethereum light node, it's connected to a 32-bit microcontroller which is user programmable.

Comment: Sure, you can install Geth or Parity there to connect directly, if the controller has the required resources. But to me, "micro-controller" just sounds like something that doesn't have the required resources.

Comment: So, the condition is the capability of micro-controller for installing Geth or Parity.

Comment: In [Elkrem](https://devpost.com/software/elkrem-development-board-for-iot-ethereum) example, their board has 2 different processors, a 1Ghz one that run Linux + Geth light client + Swarm + Whisper, the other is a 120Mhz controller that is user programmable.

Comment: According to the comments on this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/57836/23024 , isn't it **easier** to use `infura` as an **existing node**, instead of installing `Geth` or `Parity` ?

Comment: Sure it is easier to use Infura - that's one option for a bit more centrailized version.